# Facing a problem with Return URL asp dotnet core version 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Im using Identity framework When Use [Authorize] in get method the url shows https://localhost:44329/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin%2FProductTypes%2FCreate

but it should be https://localhost:44329/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin%2FProductTypes%2FCreate

Why Identity Missing in Url?

**Startup.cs file code**

```
namespace OnlineShop
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the intended result... The return URL is the url you'll be returned to after you successfully login and can pass the [Authorize] attribute

Answer (score 1):

`.AddIdentity()` does not contains build-in pages, you need add `.AddDefaultUI()` to use default UI:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddDefaultUI()          //add this line....
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```